# Triangle inequality applied to subtraction?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

So I checked out other questions and it appears my specific question wasn't answered

I was wondering if the following is valid:
$$
\lvert a - b \rvert \le \lvert a \rvert + \lvert -b \rvert = \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert \\
\therefore \; \lvert a - b \rvert \le \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert
$$

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: To make it more explicit, write $a-b = a +(-b)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's valid. You may also be interested in the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Unfortunately, the reverse triangle inequality does nothing to reverse triangle inequality:

[image]

([from Brown Sharpie](http://brownsharpie.courtneygibbons.org/?p=339))

Comment: Laughed out loud, Zev!

Comment: best answer I've ever seen :D